# Position Powershell WPF Dialogue in bottom right

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I'm trying to get the following Powershell powered WPF dialogue to display in the bottom right of the screen:

```
### SAM CAYZE ###
### BUT ALL MY CREDIT GOES TO TREVOR JONES, WHO MADE THIS AWESOME FUNCTION 
# https://smsagent.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/a-customisable-wpf-messagebox-for-powershell/
 
 
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase
 
 
Function New-WPFMessageBox {
 
    # CREDIT TO Trevor Jones:
    # https://smsagent.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/a-customisable-wpf-messagebox-for-powershell/
    
    # CHANGES
    # 2017-09-11 - Added some required assemblies in the dynamic parameters to avoid errors when run from the PS console host.
    
    # Define Parameters
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        # The popup Content
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0)]
        [Object]$Content,
 
        # The window title
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Title,
 
        # The buttons to add
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
        [ValidateSet('OK', 'OK-Cancel', 'Abort-Retry-Ignore', 'Yes-No-Cancel', 'Yes-No', 'Retry-Cancel', 'Cancel-TryAgain-Continue', 'None')]
        [array]$ButtonType = 'OK',
 
        # The buttons to add
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 3)]
        [array]$CustomButtons,
 
        # Content font size
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 4)]
        [int]$ContentFontSize = 14,
 
        # Title font size
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 5)]
        [int]$TitleFontSize = 14,
 
        # BorderThickness
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 6)]
        [int]$BorderThickness = 0,
 
        # CornerRadius
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 7)]
        [int]$CornerRadius = 8,
 
        # ShadowDepth
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 8)]
        [int]$ShadowDepth = 3,
 
        # BlurRadius
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 9)]
        [int]$BlurRadius = 20,
 
        # WindowHost
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 10)]
        [object]$WindowHost,
 
        # Timeout in seconds,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 11)]
        [int]$Timeout,
 
        # Code for Window Loaded event,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 12)]
        [scriptblock]$OnLoaded,
 
        # Code for Window Closed event,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 13)]
        [scriptblock]$OnClosed
 
    )
 
    # Dynamically Populated parameters
    DynamicParam {
        
        # Add assemblies for use in PS Console 
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing, PresentationCore
        
        # ContentBackground
        $ContentBackground = 'ContentBackground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.ContentBackground = "White"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ContentBackground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ContentBackground, $RuntimeParameter)
        
 
        # FontFamily
        $FontFamily = 'FontFamily'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)  
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.FontFamily]::Families | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($FontFamily, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($FontFamily, $RuntimeParameter)
        $PSBoundParameters.FontFamily = "Segui"
 
        # TitleFontWeight
        $TitleFontWeight = 'TitleFontWeight'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Windows.FontWeights] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.TitleFontWeight = "Normal"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($TitleFontWeight, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($TitleFontWeight, $RuntimeParameter)
 
        # ContentFontWeight
        $ContentFontWeight = 'ContentFontWeight'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Windows.FontWeights] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.ContentFontWeight = "Normal"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ContentFontWeight, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ContentFontWeight, $RuntimeParameter)
        
 
        # ContentTextForeground
        $ContentTextForeground = 'ContentTextForeground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.ContentTextForeground = "Black"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ContentTextForeground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ContentTextForeground, $RuntimeParameter)
 
        # TitleTextForeground
        $TitleTextForeground = 'TitleTextForeground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.TitleTextForeground = "Black"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($TitleTextForeground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($TitleTextForeground, $RuntimeParameter)
 
        # BorderBrush
        $BorderBrush = 'BorderBrush'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.BorderBrush = "Black"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($BorderBrush, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($BorderBrush, $RuntimeParameter)
 
 
        # TitleBackground
        $TitleBackground = 'TitleBackground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.TitleBackground = "White"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($TitleBackground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($TitleBackground, $RuntimeParameter)
 
        # ButtonTextForeground
        $ButtonTextForeground = 'ButtonTextForeground'
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $False
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute) 
        $arrSet = [System.Drawing.Brushes] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType Property | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)    
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)
        $PSBoundParameters.ButtonTextForeground = "Black"
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ButtonTextForeground, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ButtonTextForeground, $RuntimeParameter)


 
        return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }
 
    Begin {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
    }
    
    Process {
 
        # Define the XAML markup
        [XML]$Xaml = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="Window" Title="" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" Opacity="1" ShowInTaskbar="False">
        

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border>
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" Margin="10" CornerRadius="$CornerRadius" BorderThickness="$BorderThickness" BorderBrush="$($PSBoundParameters.BorderBrush)" Padding="0" >
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DSE" Color="Black" Direction="270" BlurRadius="$BlurRadius" ShadowDepth="$ShadowDepth" Opacity="0.6" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DSE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ShadowDepth" From="0" To="$ShadowDepth" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DSE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BlurRadius" From="0" To="$BlurRadius" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="False" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
        <Grid >
            <Border Name="Mask" CornerRadius="$CornerRadius" Background="$($PSBoundParameters.ContentBackground)" />
            <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="$($PSBoundParameters.ContentBackground)">
                <Grid.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}"/>
                </Grid.OpacityMask>
                <StackPanel Name="StackPanel" >                   
                    <TextBox Name="TitleBar" IsReadOnly="True" IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="$Title" Padding="10" FontFamily="$($PSBoundParameters.FontFamily)" FontSize="$TitleFontSize" Foreground="$($PSBoundParameters.TitleTextForeground)" FontWeight="$($PSBoundParameters.TitleFontWeight)" Background="$($PSBoundParameters.TitleBackground)" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"/>
                    <DockPanel Name="ContentHost" Margin="0,10,0,10"  >
                    </DockPanel>
                    <DockPanel Name="ButtonHost" LastChildFill="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
"@
 
        [XML]$ButtonXaml = @"
<Button xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="Auto" Height="30" FontFamily="Segui" FontSize="16" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" Padding="20,0,20,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Cursor="Hand"/>
"@
 
        [XML]$ButtonTextXaml = @"
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" FontFamily="$($PSBoundParameters.FontFamily)" FontSize="16" Background="Transparent" Foreground="$($PSBoundParameters.ButtonTextForeground)" Padding="20,5,20,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
"@
 
        [XML]$ContentTextXaml = @"
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Text="$Content" Foreground="$($PSBoundParameters.ContentTextForeground)" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="$($PSBoundParameters.FontFamily)" FontSize="$ContentFontSize" FontWeight="$($PSBoundParameters.ContentFontWeight)" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto" MaxWidth="500" MinWidth="50" Padding="10"/>
"@
 
        # Load the window from XAML
        
        $Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $xaml))
        $window.topmost = $true


 
        # Custom function to add a button
        Function Add-Button {
            Param($Content)
            $Button = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $ButtonXaml))
            $ButtonText = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $ButtonTextXaml))
            $ButtonText.Text = "$Content"
            $Button.Content = $ButtonText
            $Button.Content.Foreground = "Blue"
            $Button.Add_MouseEnter( {
                    $This.Content.Foreground = "Black"
                })
            $Button.Add_MouseLeave( {
                    $This.Content.Foreground = "Blue"
                })
            $Button.Add_Click( {
                    New-Variable -Name WPFMessageBoxOutput -Value $($This.Content.Text) -Option ReadOnly -Scope Script -Force
                    $Window.Close()
                })
            $Window.FindName('ButtonHost').AddChild($Button)
        }
 
        # Add buttons
        If ($ButtonType -eq "OK") {
            Add-Button -Content "OK"
        }
 
        If ($ButtonType -eq "OK-Cancel") {
            Add-Button -Content "OK"
            Add-Button -Content "Cancel"
        }
 
        If ($ButtonType -eq "Abort-Retry-Ignore") {
            Add-Button -Content "Abort"
            Add-Button -Content "Retry"
            Add-Button -Content "Ignore"
        }
 
        If ($ButtonType -eq "Yes-No-Cancel") {
            Add-Button -Content "Yes"
            Add-Button -Content "No"
            Add-Button -Content "Cancel"
        }
 
        If ($ButtonType -eq "Yes-No") {
            Add-Button -Content "Yes"
            Add-Button -Content "No"
        }
 
        If ($ButtonType -eq "Retry-Cancel") {
            Add-Button -Content "Retry"
            Add-Button -Content "Cancel"
        }
 
        If ($ButtonType -eq "Cancel-TryAgain-Continue") {
            Add-Button -Content "Cancel"
            Add-Button -Content "TryAgain"
            Add-Button -Content "Continue"
        }
 
        If ($ButtonType -eq "None" -and $CustomButtons) {
            Foreach ($CustomButton in $CustomButtons) {
                Add-Button -Content "$CustomButton"
            }
        }
 
        # Remove the title bar if no title is provided
        If ($Title -eq "") {
            $TitleBar = $Window.FindName('TitleBar')
            $Window.FindName('StackPanel').Children.Remove($TitleBar)
        }
 
        # Add the Content
        If ($Content -is [String]) {
            # Replace double quotes with single to avoid quote issues in strings
            If ($Content -match '"') {
                $Content = $Content.Replace('"', "'")
            }
        
            # Use a text box for a string value...
            $ContentTextBox = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $ContentTextXaml))
            $Window.FindName('ContentHost').AddChild($ContentTextBox)
        }
        Else {
            # ...or add a WPF element as a child
            Try {
                $Window.FindName('ContentHost').AddChild($Content) 
            }
            Catch {
                $_
            }        
        }
 
        # Enable window to move when dragged
        $Window.FindName('Grid').Add_MouseLeftButtonDown( {
                $Window.DragMove()
            })
 
        # Activate the window on loading
        If ($OnLoaded) {
            $Window.Add_Loaded( {
                    $This.Activate()
                    Invoke-Command $OnLoaded
                })
        }
        Else {
            $Window.Add_Loaded( {
                    $This.Activate()
                })
        }
    
 
        # Stop the dispatcher timer if exists
        If ($OnClosed) {
            $Window.Add_Closed( {
                    If ($DispatcherTimer) {
                        $DispatcherTimer.Stop()
                    }
                    Invoke-Command $OnClosed
                })
        }
        Else {
            $Window.Add_Closed( {
                    If ($DispatcherTimer) {
                        $DispatcherTimer.Stop()
                    }
                })
        }
    
 
        # If a window host is provided assign it as the owner
        If ($WindowHost) {
            $Window.Owner = $WindowHost
            $Window.WindowStartupLocation = "CenterOwner"
        }
 
        # If a timeout value is provided, use a dispatcher timer to close the window when timeout is reached
    
        If ($Timeout) {
            $Stopwatch = New-object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
            $TimerCode = {
                If ($Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -ge $Timeout) {
                    $Stopwatch.Stop()
                    $Window.Close()
                    $TimeoutReached = 1
                }
            }
            $DispatcherTimer = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
            $DispatcherTimer.Interval = [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(1)
            $DispatcherTimer.Add_Tick($TimerCode)
            $Stopwatch.Start()
            $DispatcherTimer.Start()
        }
 
 
        # Display the window

$null = $window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{$window.ShowDialog()}.Wait()
 
    }
}
 
###########  END OF FUNCTION  #################
 
 
$Params = @{
    Title = "Title text" 
    TitleFontSize = 20
    ButtonType = 'None'
    CustomButtons = "Reboot now","Remind me later"
    TitleBackground = 'SteelBlue'
    }
 

 
$TextBlock = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
$TextBlock.Text = "Body Text"
$TextBlock.Padding = 12
$TextBlock.FontSize = 14
$TextBlock.VerticalAlignment = "Center"
 
$StackPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
$StackPanel.Orientation = "Horizontal"
$StackPanel.AddChild($TextBlock)
 
 
 
####### DISPLAY MESSAGE ##########
New-WPFMessageBox @Params -Content $StackPanel
 
 
####### PROCESS RESULTS ##########
    If ($WPFMessageBoxOutput -eq "Reboot now")
    {
        ## TESTING CODE ### 
        # Write-Output "Proceed with Installation Clicked"
        $CustomExitCode = 0
    }
    ElseIf ($WPFMessageBoxOutput -eq "Remind me later")
    {
        ## TESTING CODE ### 
        # Write-Output "Not now Clicked"
        $CustomExitCode = 1
    }
    Else
    {
    }
 
####### FINAL OUTPUT ##########
    # Write-Output $CustomExitCode
    EXIT $CustomExitCode
```

I've placed most of the code I've tried just before the dialogue is shown:

```
        # Display the window

$null = $window.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync{$window.ShowDialog()}.Wait()
```

But nothing I've tried has worked.

I've played with the Left and Top properties in the <Window...> section, but this needs to show in the bottom right regardless of the screen result ion and DPI scaling.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to remove `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` from the Windows declaration and add

```
WindowStartupLocation="Manual" Width="380" Height="210"
```

Also remove `$Window.WindowStartupLocation = "CenterOwner"` from the `If ($WindowHost) {..}` test.

Next, under `# Load the window from XAML` put this:

```
# Load the window from XAML
    
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNodeReader -ArgumentList $xaml))
$window.Topmost = $true
$window.Left    = [System.Windows.SystemParameters]::WorkArea.Width - $window.Width
$window.Top     = [System.Windows.SystemParameters]::WorkArea.Height - $window.Height
```